# FAVAR model, stationarity and Toda & Yamamoto

Tags: pca, stationarity, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

To overcome the problems of non-starionarity and cointegration between variables, Toda and Yamamoto (1995) suggested to estimate a VAR with a number of lags sufficient to avoid the problem of autocorrelation and then add an extra lag, as exogenous variable, to preserve the asymptotic distribution of the Wald Test for testing Granger Causality.

However, since I have a huge dataset, I'd like to estimate a FAVAR model, the one proposed by Bernanke (2005). Reading it's paper, when he computes the PCA to estimate the PC to plug into the model, he transforms all the original variables to induce stationarity.

My question is: since I'm using the approach of Toda and Yamamoto, so I can neglect the stationarity, can I neglect it too when computing the PCA and so use the variables in levels also to estimate the liner combinations?

Comment: More complete references to the two papers would be nice to have.